# outlook.com can't delete Gmail contact with synchro link deleted

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, outlook.com, synchronization

I synced Gmail in outlook.com to use Gtalk one week ago.

My contacts are being synchronized with Gmails, I wanted to remove the synchronization link between my two accounts to clean my contacts on outlook.com because I don't want Gmail contacts in my outlook.com contacts.

The problem is that after a week without synchronization, link deleted on the two accounts, my Gmail contacts are still in my list on outlook.com.
**It is impossible to delete a contact on outlook.com** because according to the website, the contact is managed via Gmail.

Frustrated, I even deleted all of my Gmail contacts, but they stay in outlook.com and can't delete them.

I tried posting on the Microsoft forum but it does not work.
I hope you can help me.

Someone know how I can delete contacts (in outlook.com) added by my synchronization with Gmail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem! I had to disconnect and re-sync and disconnect for it to finally get rid of them.

https://account.live.com/consent/manage

**Manage accounts**

Remove Connection Completely.
It should take a moment and then the contacts should disappear. if it doesn't work re-connect to Gmail again and disconnect again. otherwise I have no idea how I got it to finally work. (I think you have to be under the manage acct. for it to read the action.)

Comment: Thanks for your experience. I have Edited my post to add the process.

Answer (score 0):

A way to delete them from outlook.com contacts hub

- The initial status is that my Gmail contacts stay in my outlook.com contact list when the link into the two accounts is deleted. I can't delete Gmail contacts on outlook.com.

  1. Disconnect the link in the two accounts.
  2. Go on Gmail, export your contacts and delete all.
  3. Re-sync your Gmail account on Outlook.com. After 5 mins, all Gmail contacts will be deleted on your outlook.com contact list.
  4. Delete the link between the two accounts.
  5. Go on Gmail an import your contacts.

Comment: The original Asker had edited this into the question. Since it is an answer I've moved it to its own (Community Wiki) answer post. Should the Asker return and add their own answer I'll get rid of this.